# Why is the Properties Array returning as undefined?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to push an item into a array stored in the properties,
I'm getting an error: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'value')

in the props I have:

ILinkItemProps.ts

```
export interface ILinkItemProps {
  id:string;
  title:string;
  action:string;
  anchorid:string;
  trans:string;
}

export class LinksItem implements ILinkItemProps {
    constructor (
        public id: string  = null, 
        public title: string = null, 
        public action: string = null,
        public anchorid: string = null,
        public trans: string = null) { }
}
```

ILinksProp.ts

```
import {LinksItem} from './ILinkItemProps';
export interface ILinksProps {
    linkItems:Array<LinksItem>;
}
```

in the webpart.ts I have:-

```
public render(): void {
    const element: React.ReactElement<ILinksProps> = React.createElement(
      links,
      {
 linkItems: this.properties.linkItems,
 updateEditLink: (index: number) => {
            let arr = this.properties.linkItems;
            if (arr?.push) {
              arr.push(new LinksItem());
            } else {
              console.log('arr is undefined or null');
            }
        }

    }
)
```

has anyone got any ideas why the Array is undefined?

Answer (score 0):

Using `this.props` rather than `this.properties` should give you access to props passed to the component. Here is your example rewritten to use `this.props`:

```
import React from 'react';

export interface ILinkItemProps {
  id:string|null;
  title:string|null;
  action:string|null;
  anchorid:string|null;
  trans:string|null;
}

export class LinksItem implements ILinkItemProps {
    constructor (
      public id: string|null  = null, 
      public title: string|null = null, 
      public action: string|null = null,
      public anchorid: string|null = null,
      public trans: string|null = null) { }
}

export interface ILinksProps {
  linkItems:Array<ILinkItemProps>;
}

export class MyList extends React.Component<ILinksProps> {
  render() {
    return <div>List count: {this.props.linkItems.length}</div>;
  }
}

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <MyList linkItems={[
      {id: '1'} as ILinkItemProps
    ]} />
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

OK I have sorted this with,

```
    if (!this.properties.linkItems?.push) {
      this.properties.linkItems=[];
    }
    this.properties.linkItems.push(new LinksItem())
```

it checks if it can push it, if not set it as an array then push into it.
I'm wondering whether its a bug as it set in the properties as an array.